# Unknown error on Facebook Messenger after upgrade to xcode8

Tags: xcode8

Iam currently using the following code with proper LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.
NSString *customURL = @"fb-messenger://";

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{

    [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:cropped withOptions:nil];

}
```

The same code is working with xcode7 but not xcode8.

The messenger is populated with image but on clicking send "unknown error sorry something went wrong" message is displayed.

Requesting help as soon as possible.

Comment: Help required if any Xcode 8 specific settings are required for the above mentioned issue as I am still unable to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. I added platform and bundle id in app's settings on fb dashboard.

You can find how to do it in this tutorial at step 4
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios